# check if sqlite json array elements in range

Tags: json, sqlite, join, where-clause, exists

I have a table which contains a json column that has an array field, I want to check if the numbers inside the array belong to a range, that is if each element passes the predicate to be greater than X and lesser than Y,

```sql
select nom.id, nom.doc
from nom
join json_each(nom.doc, "$.rate") e
where e.value > 0 and e.value < 7
```

I'd expect this to work but it doesn't, I understand that json_each returns a table, and I think maybe using grouping or aggregation I could get what I want, but I want to know if there is another way, I would like to not rely on aggregation, as I would want to for example, check if all elements pass a predicate, for example, if all are greater than X, or if I where working with strings, if they all match a pattern etc.

sample data:

```
id: 1, doc: {rate: [1, 2, 3]}
id: 2, doc: {rate: [1, 2, 3, 5 9]}
```

If I have those two records, I'd like to get those whose rate has values lesser than 7 and greater than 0, for example, record with id 2 should not appear in the query I desire.

Comment: Post sample data of your table to clarify what you want.

Comment: Hi @forpas, just did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to extract all the values of the array inside a CTE and use `NOT EXISTS` in the main query to check if all values of a certain `id` pass the predicate:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT n.id, n.doc, e.value
  FROM nom n JOIN json_each(n.doc, "$.rate") e
)
SELECT n.id, n.doc
FROM nom n
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM cte c
  WHERE c.id = n.id AND NOT <your predicate>
);
```

Change `<your predicate>` to something like:

```
(c.value > 0 AND c.value < 7)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=318426c7b544e394c0c3fd646d1f2efd).